# Como fazer transition usando function no js ONCLICK

Tags: javascript, css, transição

Boa tarde estou com problemas para estilizar uma animação, minha intenção é criar um function no css que possa realizar uma transição de uma imagem até o topo usando transition no css, quero que a img fique margin-top: 0; quando for clicada e fique fixa lá, até ser clicada novamente e volte para sua posição inicial.

```js
var selecionarpergaminho = document.getElementById("pergaminho");

function open() {
    selecionarpergaminho.style.marginTop = "100";

    alert("algo");
}

selecionarpergaminho.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selecionarpergaminho.classList.toggle('toggle');
};
```

```css
#pergaminho{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30vh;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
#pergaminho:hover {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/fan.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/function.js"></script>
    <title>Alexandre Shiguemi Ito</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <img src="/img/header.png" id="pergaminho" onclick="troca()">
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: em resumo ao clicar na imagem sob e fixa no top e não ao passar o ponteiro do mouse ela vai subindo e fixa,certo?... pq atualmente só ao passar do mouse ele mexe.

Comment: Isso eu consegui fazer ele ficar em cima, porem agora o problema é fazer ele voltar para onde estava, ele esta fixando no topo do site e quando clico nele nao esta retornando.

Comment: Isso muito obrigado, eu consegui resolver de outra forma se quiser dar uma olhada, mas acho q o seu parece estar mais correto pois minha img esta muito alta

Comment: Deve ser pelo `position: relative;` pensei que deveria respeitar um limite.

Comment: Consigo entrar em contato com vc por outra forma??